# Debugging on my iPhone problem

Tags: debugging, certificate, keychain

Hey, I'm getting this error when I'm trying to debug on my iPhone.

CodeSign error: Certificate identity 'iPhone Developer: Sweppi (YT9AK96EZ4)' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one.

I know that I need to delete the Certificate in my keychain but where in the key chain do I find this Certificate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Keychain Access program. Select `Certificate` categories on your lower-left panel. And make sure there are no "Sweppi" dups.